# Can't connect to php7 fpm docker container from within an apache 2 docker container

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**Similar question have been asked many times and I have gone through most of them and still I am not able to solve the problem.**

I am running Apache2 and PHP 7 FPM in different docker containers and they are not able to connect to each other. **The connection fails with following errors.**

```
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:51.743322 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441754191616] proxy_util.c(2422): [client 172.18.0.1:36332] AH00947: connected /var/www/html/info.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:51.743387 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 336:tid 140441754191616] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:51.743405 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 336:tid 140441754191616] [client 172.18.0.1:36332] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:51.743410 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441754191616] proxy_util.c(2175): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809604 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.18.0.1:36442] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809646 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.18.0.1:36442] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809676 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] mod_proxy.c(1160): [client 172.18.0.1:36442] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809687 2017] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(879): [client 172.18.0.1:36442] AH01076: url: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/info.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809694 2017] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(886): [client 172.18.0.1:36442] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/info.php
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809703 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] proxy_util.c(2160): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809712 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] proxy_util.c(2213): [client 172.18.0.1:36442] AH00944: connecting fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/info.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809840 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] proxy_util.c(2422): [client 172.18.0.1:36442] AH00947: connected /var/www/html/info.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809927 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809946 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] [client 172.18.0.1:36442] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Tue Sep 19 00:05:56.809953 2017] [proxy:debug] [pid 336:tid 140441672480512] proxy_util.c(2175): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

**Below is my docker-compose file**

```
version: '2'
services:
    php:
        build: ./etc/php/
        volumes:
          - ./etc/php/config/php.ini:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
          - ./etc/php/config/www.conf:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
          - ./etc/php/config/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf
          - ./etc/php/logs/php-fpm.log:/var/log/php-fpm.log 
          - ./etc/php/logs/fpm-php.www.log:/var/log/fpm-php.www.log
          - ./source/:/var/www/html/
        expose:
          - 9000
        ports:
          - "9000:9000"
        links:
          - mysql

    apache2:
        build: ./etc/apache/
        volumes:
          - ./source/:/var/www/html/
          - ./etc/apache/config/sites-enabled/:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
          - ./etc/apache/config/conf-enabled/:/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
          - ./etc/apache/logs/error.log:/var/log/apache2/error.log
          - ./etc/apache/logs/access.log:/var/log/apache2/access.log
          - ./etc/apache/logs/sm-error.log:/var/log/apache2/sm-error.log
          - ./etc/apache/logs/sm-access.log:/var/log/apache2/sm-access.log
        expose:
          - 80
          - 443
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
          - "443:443"
        links:
          - php

    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes:
          - ./etc/mysql/data/:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./etc/mysql/config/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/
        ports:
          - "3307:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: sp
            MYSQL_USER: spadmin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        links:
            - mysql
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
```

**Below is my docker file for apache2.**

```
#Get the base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

#Install Apache
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
      apache2 \
      apache2-utils

# Enable modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod proxy
RUN a2enmod proxy_fcgi

# Add user to www-data
RUN groupadd 1000
RUN usermod -a -G 1000 www-data
RUN usermod -a -G staff www-data

RUN service apache2 restart

# Run config
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl" ]
CMD [ "-D", "FOREGROUND" ]
```

**Below is my virtual host file for apache2.**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    </FilesMatch>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/sm-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/sm-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Below is my PHP-FPM docker file.**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install PHP
RUN apt-get clean && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y locales \
    curl \ 
    software-properties-common \ 
    git && \
    locale-gen en_AU.UTF-8   
RUN LC_ALL=en_AU.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes php7.1-bcmath \ 
                php7.1-bz2 \ 
                php7.1-cli \
                php7.1-common \
                php7.1-curl \
                php7.1-cgi \ 
                php7.1-dev \
                php7.1-fpm \
                php7.1-gd \
                php-ldap \
                php7.1-gmp \
                php7.1-intl \
                php7.1-json \
                php7.1-mbstring \
                php7.1-mcrypt \
                php7.1-mysql \
                php-sqlite3 \
                php7.1-opcache \
                php7.1-phpdbg \
                hp7.1-pspell \
                php7.1-readline \
                php7.1-recode \ 
                php7.1-soap \ 
                php7.1-tidy \
                php7.1-xml \
                php7.1-xmlrpc \
                php7.1-xsl \
                php7.1-zip \
                php-xdebug

# Install Composer
RUN curl https://getcomposer.org/installer > composer-setup.php && php composer-setup.php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && rm composer-setup.php

# Clean files
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Run PHP-FPM
CMD ["php-fpm7.1"]
```

Below is the output of docker ps command.

```
a85830192ad4        spendingmanager_apache2   "/usr/sbin/apache2..."   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   spendingmanager_apache2_1
4574c977d0d4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin     "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp                         spendingmanager_phpmyadmin_1
82735fa580e8        spendingmanager_php       "php-fpm7.1"             15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                       spendingmanager_php_1
32422e934247        mysql:latest              "docker-entrypoint..."   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp                       spendingmanager_mysql_1
```

**Note: PHP-FPM is listening for connections on port 9000 and its working properly. When I try to access it from my host OS (for instance http://localhost/ instead of http://localhost:8080 I am able to connect and get the desired output).**

I have also tried setting up permission on the `www/html` and try making `www-data` the owner.

Can someone please help me get this working?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"` should be `SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"`. Btw, you don't need to bind fpm ports to host because php and apache containers are linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your examples `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is local to the containers (not the host). So, when Apache tries to connect to FPM at `127.0.0.1:9000`, it is actually trying to connect to itself (the Apache container only).

What you want to do is have Apache connect to the FPM container. The easiest way to do this with Docker networking is to use the service name from Docker Compose. In your case, the service name is `php` and will be available at the DNS name `php` from the Apache container.

Thus, your Apache configuration should be:

```
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andy-shin this fixed the problem. I was looking into this for days. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error and just figured out the reason by struggling almost a whole day.

In my case, the problem was having IP v6 enabled in my VPS while there was no real IP6 address assigned into my interface.

I just disabled the IPV6 and things started work normally again. (Disable IPv6/IPv4 if it is not in use )

step 1 - edit the sysctl.conf file using the following command in your shell

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

step 2 - add the following two lines to disable IPv6

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

step 3 - save and close the file (Esc -> :wq)

step 4 - for immediate effect run the following code in shell

```
sysctl -p
```